# High Distance Bluetooth Transmitter Microchip

Tags: bluetooth

I’m trying to develop a product and a bit new to this type of development and technology. As I continue to build a newer prototype, I’m looking for:
1) needs to be small, like the 1 inch x 1inch and 1/2 inch thick or smaller, assuming microchip is the way to go?
2) needs to transmit far, hoping for 100meters outdoors
3) needs to transmit to a mobile Android or IOS phone 
4) low energy is preferred

Thought someone might be able to point me in the right direction for the transmitter. Just a Newbie trying to provide value for mankind

Comment: A half-cubic inch for power, transmitter, and antenna for 100m LoS is probably pushing it. But you say nothing about how much data how often, so nobody can help. Even if it was OT for SO, which it isn't. Maybe the embedded or IoT SE.

Comment: You'd probably also need to include whether or not it really needs to be BT or BLE, what else it requires in terms of capabilities (e.g, is an ESP8266 close enough) etc. But if you've already built a prototype it's not clear what additional information someone else could provide outside of your own research.